# Can I override assets of a (composer) Laravel package?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I use [this package](https://github.com/mdixon18/fontawesome/) for adding Font Awesome icons in Laravel Nova. However I would like to use Font Awesome pro and this file [references only the free version](https://github.com/mdixon18/fontawesome/blob/master/resources/js/components/IndexField.vue). How can I override only this file without having to make a fork of the package? Is there a way with the service container?